# How are opponents in random games determined?

Tags: hero-academy

When I start a random game how does the game determine who to pit me against?

Is there any form of match-making to make sure I don't get assigned a game against the world expert while I have barely finished the tutorial?

Comment: Fairly sure it's only based on who is currently looking for opponents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no match-making in Hero Academy.  You will be assigned a game against someone else who has recently started a random game and one of you will be randomly assigned first turn.

So, yes, you could end up against an expert just as easily as you could end up against someone who plays two turns and never plays again.

However, the community is pretty friendly - most experts will chat with you and help you out, if you ask.

When you think you have become an expert, there is a [fan run league](http://www.robotentertainmentfans.com/hero-academy/league-home/) that you can join.  The website is pretty ugly (and you cannot submit games via Safari), but the competition is good.